# Is MinimumBackgroundFetchInterval take static time interval when application running in background mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want run an api in interval of 12 hours either app is in foreground mode or in background mode. I enabled `"Background Fetch"` mode for background in capabilities and using following code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` delegate method:

```
[application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:60*12];
```

Here I am not using UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum because not sure for random time. Also I implemented a method in AppDelegate:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
    // API calling implemented
}
```

But, my problem is above delegate method is not calling by system according to time interval I provided for 12 hours (12*60) rather it is calling randomly and some time does not call. Can any one please let me know how the above delegate method can call by system in fixed time of interval?

Comment: You can't control the interval. The minimum refresh time is a hint to iOS as to the minimum time that should elapse between invocations of the fetch function,  but iOS will tune the frequency based on activity and how often and the times of day when your fetch returns new data and when it doesn't.  Refer to "fetching small amounts of content opportunistically" in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: See also https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1623100-setminimumbackgroundfetchinterva

Comment: Old thread but note that the value provided to setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval is in seconds so for 12 hours you'd need to specify 12*60*60.